# Lost all the directories with sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/* in ubuntu 16

Tags: data-loss

I was unable to empty my trash so I used the below command:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

and it deleted everything from all the directories, home and downloads

Can any one please help?

Comment: You may have accidentally run `sudo rm -rf ~/ .local/share/Trash/`. Note the space between `~/` and `.local`. That would delete your home directory.

Comment: Another cautionary example on why sudo should be used with great care, especially when issuing destructive commands such as rm.

Answer (score 3):

The command `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` will only remove the contents of your local Trash directory.  Additionally, for future reference, deleting your own user trash does not require sudo privileges.

Your `$HOME` files structure may indeed be deleted as you say, but the command you posted wouldn't do that.

Comment: It would if they put a space after ~/.

Answer (score 2):

first don't run the system to avoid overwriting data. boot from a live CD 
extundelete is a good program for recovering files by reading inodes.

Answer (score 1):

Run a liveCD / USB and mount the partition containing your lost files as readonly. ex. If your /home partition is on sda2, execute these commands:

```
mkdir ~/recovery/

sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda2 ~/recovery/
```

Recover your user directory and all it's contents:

```
sudo extundelete /dev/sda2 --restore-directory /home/username/
```

Comment: You need to expand on your answer. What is extundelete? How do you install/run it? You can't modify/fix a directory that's mounted ro. Also, best not to answer the same question more than once... better to edit your first answer with additional details.